# report memory and cpu usage - matlab - on multicore linux server

Tags: linux, performance, matlab, multicore

we would need to know how much memory and cpu time a matlab process had used with all of it's spawned threads. If I understand it correctly, all the threads will pop up as new processes with new process-ids but the CMD name will remain the same.

so I thought about creating a demon which append the usage in every n sec:

```
ps -o %cpu,%mem,cmd -C MATLAB | grep "[0-9]+" >> matlab_log
```

and later counting and summing up the ratios multiplied by the demon tick time.

I wonder if there is an easier way, or I missing something, or simply just exist some tool more handy for this job?

Cheers

Comment: Java available? why not use [JMX](https://blogs.oracle.com/jmxetc/entry/what_is_jmx)?

Comment: don't know about memory, but for CPU time use the [matlab profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/profile.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the BSD Process Accounting utilities (package `acct` on Debian and Ubuntu) you can use the `sa(8)` utility to summarize executions or give you semi-detailed execution logs:

```
$ lastcomm
...
man               F  X sarnold  pts/3      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:21
man               F  X sarnold  pts/3      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:21
vim                    sarnold  pts/3      0.05 secs Fri May  4 16:20
sa                     sarnold  pts/3      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:20
sa                     sarnold  pts/3      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:20
bzr                    sarnold  pts/3      0.99 secs Fri May  4 16:19
apt-get          S     root     pts/1      0.44 secs Fri May  4 16:18
dpkg                   root     pts/1      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:19
dpkg                   root     pts/1      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:19
dpkg                   root     pts/1      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:19
apt-get           F    root     pts/1      0.00 secs Fri May  4 16:19
...
```

```
$ sa
     633      15.22re       0.09cp         0avio      6576k
      24       8.51re       0.03cp         0avio      6531k   ***other*
       2       0.31re       0.02cp         0avio     10347k   apt-get
       3       0.02re       0.02cp         0avio      9667k   python2.7
      18       0.04re       0.01cp         0avio      5444k   dpkg
       2       0.01re       0.01cp         0avio     13659k   debsums
...
```

The format of the `acct` file is documented in `acct(5)`, so you could write your own programs to parse the files if none of the standard tools lets you express the queries you want.

Probably the largest downside to the BSD process accounting utilities is that the kernel will only update the process accounting log when processes exit, because many of the summary numbers are only available once another process `wait(2)`s for it -- so currently running processes are completely overlooked by the utilities.

These utilities may be sufficient though; these utilities is how compute centers billed their clients, back when compute centers were popular...

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `top`:

```
top -b -n 1 | grep MATLAB

14226 user      39  19 2476m 1.4g  26m S 337.2  9.2  24:44.60 MATLAB
25878 user      39  19 2628m 1.6g  26m S  92.0 10.6  21:07.36 MATLAB
14363 user      39  19 2650m 1.4g  26m S  79.7  9.1  23:58.38 MATLAB
14088 user      39  19 2558m 1.4g  26m S  61.3  9.1  25:14.53 MATLAB
14648 user      39  19 2629m 1.6g  26m S  55.2 10.5  22:03.20 MATLAB
14506 user      39  19 2613m 1.5g  26m S  49.0  9.4  22:32.47 MATLAB
14788 user      39  19 2599m 1.6g  26m S  49.0 10.3  20:44.78 MATLAB
25650 user      39  19 2608m 1.6g  26m S  42.9 10.2  25:08.38 MATLAB
```

or to get fieldnames too:

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 7 | tail -n 1; top -b -n 1 | grep MATLAB

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
14226 user      39  19 2476m 1.4g  26m S 337.2  9.2  24:44.60 MATLAB
25878 user      39  19 2628m 1.6g  26m S  92.0 10.6  21:07.36 MATLAB
14363 user      39  19 2650m 1.4g  26m S  79.7  9.1  23:58.38 MATLAB
14088 user      39  19 2558m 1.4g  26m S  61.3  9.1  25:14.53 MATLAB
14648 user      39  19 2629m 1.6g  26m S  55.2 10.5  22:03.20 MATLAB
14506 user      39  19 2613m 1.5g  26m S  49.0  9.4  22:32.47 MATLAB
14788 user      39  19 2599m 1.6g  26m S  49.0 10.3  20:44.78 MATLAB
25650 user      39  19 2608m 1.6g  26m S  42.9 10.2  25:08.38 MATLAB
```